# Export CSV functionality for gird inside admin edit form tab magento

Tags: export-to-csv, magento-1.9

I have a magento grid collection inside admin edit form tab.I need a export csv functionality for the grid.Its working fine with full grid list without search filters.How to export csv for the filtered collection as well?

Answer (score 5):

Go to your module or extension folder then /Block/Adminhtml/Blog/Grid.php. Open this Grid.php file and search the function `protected function _prepareCollection()` and add the following code under this function before `return parent::_prepareColumns();`.

```
$this->addExportType('*/*/exportCsv', Mage::helper('blog')->__('CSV'));
$this->addExportType('*/*/exportXml', Mage::helper('blog')->__('XML'));
```

After add this code it may be looks like that:
Next, in this extension or module folder go to /controllers/Adminhtml/ and open the controller file and add the following code under the class (add the code bottom of the page before last '}')

```
public function exportCsvAction()
    {
        $fileName   = 'blog.csv';
        $content    = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('[your-module-name]/adminhtml_[your-module-name]_grid')
            ->getCsv();

        $this->_sendUploadResponse($fileName, $content);
    }

    public function exportXmlAction()
    {
        $fileName   = 'blog.xml';
        $content    = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('[your-module-name]/adminhtml_[your-module-name]_grid')
            ->getXml();

        $this->_sendUploadResponse($fileName, $content);
    }

    protected function _sendUploadResponse($fileName, $content, $contentType='application/octet-stream')
    {
        $response = $this->getResponse();
        $response->setHeader('HTTP/1.1 200 OK','');
        $response->setHeader('Pragma', 'public', true);
        $response->setHeader('Cache-Control', 'must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0', true);
        $response->setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename='.$fileName);
        $response->setHeader('Last-Modified', date('r'));
        $response->setHeader('Accept-Ranges', 'bytes');
        $response->setHeader('Content-Length', strlen($content));
        $response->setHeader('Content-type', $contentType);
        $response->setBody($content);
        $response->sendResponse();
        die;
    }
```

Now replace the [your-module-name] text with your extension or module name and save then check.

*** Please like if this post help you!***